# Indicate minimal path sum

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization, formatting

Described on the page:
http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-81-find-the-minimal-path-sum-from-the-top-left-to-the-bottom-right-by-moving-right-and-down/

It is an example of the solution indicated in **red font**.

Solution in the Mathematica looks like this:

```
grid={
{131,673,234,103,18},
{201,96,342,965,150},
{630,803,746,422,111},
{537,699,497,121,956},
{805,732,524,37,331}
      };

MinPath[i_, j_] := MinPath[i, j] =  (* Memoization *)
grid[[i, j]] + Piecewise[{
{Min[MinPath[i + 1, j], MinPath[i, j + 1]], i < Length[grid] && j < Length[grid[[i]]]},
{MinPath[i + 1, j], i < Length[grid]},
{MinPath[i, j + 1], j < Length[grid[[i]]]}},
0]

$RecursionLimit = 1000;
MinPath[1, 1]
```

**Result: 2427**

But how to determine the cells (their position) from which formed the solution? Mark by red font?

131 -> 201 -> 96 -> 342 -> 746 -> 422 -> 121 -> 37 -> 331

Position: {1,1} -> {2,1} -> {2,2} -> {2,3} -> {3,3} -> {3,4} -> {4,4} -> {5,4} -> {5,5}

[image]

How to determine the route that went algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a slight modification of your `MinPath` function so that it takes a matrix as input

```
ClearAll[MinPathF, nextF]
MinPathF[mat_][i_, j_] := MinPathF[mat][i, j] = mat[[i, j]] + 
  Piecewise[{{Min[MinPathF[mat][i + 1, j], MinPathF[mat][i, j + 1]], 
          i < Length[mat] && j < Length[mat[[i]]]},
      {MinPathF[mat][i + 1, j], i < Length[mat]}, 
      {MinPathF[mat][i, j + 1], j < Length[mat[[i]]]}}, 0]
```

you can construct a function to generate the path

```
nextF[mat_][{i_, j_}] := If[i < Length[mat] && j < Length[mat[[i]]], 
  If[MinPathF[mat][i + 1, j] < MinPathF[mat][i, j + 1], {i + 1, j}, {i, j + 1}], 
  If[i < Length[mat], {i + 1, j}, If[j < Length[mat[[i]]], {i, j + 1}, {}]]]
```

Examples:

```
path = Most@NestWhileList[nextF[grid], {1, 1}, ! # === {} &]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {5,  5}}

```
Grid @ MapAt[Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Background -> Red] &, 
       grid, path]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively,

```
Grid[grid, Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, Thread[path -> Red]}, 
 ItemStyle -> Directive[Bold, 24], Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
randommat = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, {10, 12}]; 

Grid@ MapAt[Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], Background -> Red] &, 
    randommat, Most@NestWhileList[nextF[randommat], {1, 1}, ! # === {} &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to be able to extract the path from your recursive memoized function, but I couldn't make it happen.

But here is a function to find the minimum path from the upper left to the bottom right corners of an array of numbers,

```
minimalpathsum[grid_] := 
 Module[{dims, vertcoords, graph, weights, path, indices},
  dims = Dimensions@grid;
  vertcoords = Flatten[Array[{#2, #1} &, dims], 1];
  graph = GridGraph[Reverse@dims,
    DirectedEdges -> True,
    VertexCoordinates -> vertcoords];
  weights = (graph // EdgeList) /. 
    a_ \[DirectedEdge] b_ :> Flatten[grid][[b]];
  graph = GridGraph[Reverse@dims,
    VertexCoordinates -> vertcoords,
    EdgeWeight -> weights,
    DirectedEdges -> True];
  path = FindShortestPath[graph, 1, Times @@ dims];
  indices = Reverse /@ vertcoords[[path]];
  Print[Row[{"indices =", indices}]];
  Print[Row[{"sum =", Total@Extract[grid, indices]}]];
  ArrayPlot[
   ReplacePart[
    ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@grid], indices -> 1], 
   Epilog -> {Red, 
     MapIndexed[Text[Style[#1, 18], Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, 
      Reverse[grid], {2}]}, Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 400]
  ]
```

You can test it on your array:

```
minimalpathsum@{{131, 673, 234, 103, 18}, {201, 96, 342, 965, 
   150}, {630, 803, 746, 422, 111}, {537, 699, 497, 121, 956}, {805, 
   732, 524, 37, 331}}
```

[image]

Or on a larger, random array,

```
grid = RandomInteger[200, {15, 10}];
minimalpathsum@grid
```

[image]

### How it works

First we make a `GridGraph` the same size as the matrix, with the vertices labeled in the same order,

```
graph = GridGraph[{5, 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Reverse@Array[{#2, #1} &, {5, 5}], 1], 
  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Next we assign the edge weights to be the value of the matrix element it ends on,

```
weights = (graph // EdgeList) /. 
   a_ \[DirectedEdge] b_ :> Flatten[grid][[b]];
graph = GridGraph[{5, 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Reverse@Array[{#2, #1} &, {5, 5}], 1], 
  EdgeWeight -> weights, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
  DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

And now we can just use `FindShortestPath` to get the desired path,

```
path = FindShortestPath[graph, 1, 25]
(* {1, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 24, 25} *)
```

And extract the matrix elements from the path,

```
Flatten[grid][[path]]
Total@%
(* {131, 201, 96, 342, 746, 422, 121, 37, 331} *)
(* 2427 *)
```

An easy way to find the position of these elements in the original array is

```
First@Position[grid, #] & /@ Flatten[grid][[path]]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5,
   4}, {5, 5}} *)
```

You can show the path with `HighlightGraph`

```
HighlightGraph[graph, path, 
 Prolog -> {Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.05], 
   Arrow /@ Partition[GraphEmbedding[graph][[path]], 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 much much nicer than my monstrosity and thanks for educating me about highlighting! :)

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks, I'm very new to using `Graph`s so it's fun to practice.  You were able to answer what OP wanted more than I at first (a list of positions in the original matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Just another way (but not desired presentation style):

```
grid = {{131, 673, 234, 103, 18}, {201, 96, 342, 965, 150}, {630, 803,
     746, 422, 111}, {537, 699, 497, 121, 956}, {805, 732, 524, 37, 
    331}};
dim = Dimensions[grid];
vw = Catenate@
   MapIndexed[ (#2[[2]] - 1) 5 + #2[[1]] -> #1 &, grid, {2}];
s = GridGraph[dim, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Join @@ Table[{j, k}, {j, 1, 5, 1}, {k, 5, 1, -1}], 
   ImageSize -> 400];
gr = GridGraph[dim, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Join @@ Table[{j, k}, {j, 1, 5, 1}, {k, 5, 1, -1}], 
   VertexLabels -> vw, ImageSize -> 400];
a = FindPath[gr, 1, 25, Infinity, All];
an = Total /@ (a /. vw);
min = Min[an];
res = Extract[a, Position[an, min]];
c1 = {s, gr, 
     HighlightGraph[gr, PathGraph[#], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
      ImageSize -> 400], #, Total@(# /. vw)} & /@ res;
cand = Pick[a, Sort[#] == # & /@ a];
sum = Total /@ (cand /. vw);
answer = Extract[cand, Position[sum, Min[sum]]];
c2 = {s, gr, 
     HighlightGraph[gr, PathGraph[#], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick", 
      ImageSize -> 400], #, Total@(# /. vw)} & /@ answer;
Grid[{c1[[1]], c2[[1]]}, Frame -> All]
```

The first path is shortest. The desired path (without backtracking) is the second.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can also use @Jason B. method to find maximum cost path by just doing `1/grid`

```
weights = (graph // EdgeList) /.a_ \[DirectedEdge] b_ :> Flatten[1/grid][[b]];
graph = GridGraph[dim, VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Reverse@Array[{#2, #1} &, dim], 1], EdgeWeight -> weights, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
  DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

```
path = FindShortestPath[graph, 1, 25]
    Flatten[grid][[path]]
    Total@%
```

> {131, 201, 630, 803, 746, 497, 121, 956, 331}
>
> 4416

```
HighlightGraph[graph, path, 
 Prolog -> {Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.05], 
   Arrow /@ Partition[GraphEmbedding[graph][[path]], 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here i am modifying the answer given by @kglr slightly to find both the maximum and the minimum cost path.

```
pathMatrix[matr_, Oper_: Max] := Module[{sum, nextF, i, j},
With[{dim = Dimensions@matr},
With[{row = First@dim, col = Last@dim},
  maxSum[r_, c_] := maxSum[r, c] = matr[[r, c]] + Which[
       (r < row) && (c < col),
      Oper[ maxSum[r, c + 1], maxSum[r + 1, c]],
      r < row, maxSum[r + 1, c],
      c < col, maxSum[r, c + 1],
      True, 0
      ];

  sum = maxSum[1, 1];

  Set @@ Hold[nextF[{i_, j_}],
    Evaluate@Switch[Oper, Min,

      Which[i < row && j < col, 
       If[maxSum[i + 1, j] < maxSum[i, j + 1], {i + 1, j}, {i, 
         j + 1}],
       i < row, {i + 1, j}, j < col, {i, j + 1}, True, {}],
      Max,

      Which[i < row && j < col, 
       If[maxSum[i + 1, j] > maxSum[i, j + 1], {i + 1, j}, {i, 
         j + 1}],
       i < row, {i + 1, j}, j < col, {i, j + 1}, True, {}]]];
  ];
];
Print@sum;
Most@NestWhileList[nextF, {1, 1}, ! # === {} &]
];
```

(*to find the minimum cost path*)

```
grid = {{131, 673, 234, 103, 18}, {201, 96, 342, 965, 150}, {630, 803,
 746, 422, 111}, {537, 699, 497, 121, 956}, {805, 732, 524, 37, 
331}};

Clear@maxSum;
path = pathMatrix[grid, Min];

Grid[grid, Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, Thread[path -> LightBlue]}, 
ItemStyle -> Directive[Bold, 24], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

(*to find the maximum cost path*)

[image]